# Can anyone help me with this do Carmo question?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

(Geodesic frame). Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ and let $p \in M$. Show that there exists a neighborhood 
$U \subset M$ of $p$ and $n$ vector fields $E_1,...,E_n \in X(U)$, orthonormal at each point of $U$, such that, at $p$, $\nabla_{E_i}E_j(p) = 0$. 
Such a family $E_i, i = 1,..., n,$ of vector fields is called a (local) 
geodesic frame at p.

**Question:** I don't know how I can to prove the step: $\nabla_{E_i}E_j(p)=0$.

I am using $\exp(te_i)$ as a geodesic for this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know how i can to prove the step: \nabla_{E_i}E_j(р) = О. I using  exp(te_i) as geodesic for this.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimensin $n$ and $p\in M$.

Consider $U$ to be a convex neighbourhood around $p$. Choose an orthogonal basis $\{ X_1(p),\cdots , X_n(p)\}$ at $T_p(M)$. Define for each $q\in U$, $X_i(q)$ be the parralel transport of $X_i(p)$ with respect to the unique geodesic joining $p$ and $q$. As we know parralel transport is an isometry (which is essentially some exercise in Do Carmo) $\langle X_i,X_j\rangle= \delta_{ij}$. And  $\nabla_{X_i}X_j(p)=0$ (because $d(exp_p)(0)$ is the identity map on $T_p(M)$, so follows from the construction) .

Comment: It was my first intention to answer something along these lines. But then I asked myself why th $X_i$ are actually _smooth_ vector fields?

Comment: I don't see how to do the last step.

Comment: @FariasFilho I added one extra line for you.

Comment: @hase_olaf Yes $X_i$'s are smooth, because you are considering parallel transport inside the convex nbd along geodesics, which are smooth. So everything is a smooth operation here

Comment: ok @Anubhav, so i have to show E_i=d(exp_p)(0)?

Comment: @FariasFilho what? No this is the derivative map which push forward the operations from one tangent space to another.

Comment: i am think that E_i=e_i=\frac{d(exp(te_i)}{dt}. Its not ok?

Comment: @FariasFilho please use latex, I cannot understand what  you are writing.

Comment: E_i=\frac{d(\exp(te_i))}{dt}|_t=0=e_i  its ok @Anubhav?

Comment: @FariasFilho Put $$ sign

Comment: ok sorry! $$E_i=\frac{d(\exp(te_i))}{dt}|_{t=0}=e_i $$

Comment: @FariasFilho yes, you got it right.

Comment: @FariasFilho did you get my solutionh? In that case you can accept my solution and upvote it.